# How should I ensure that my Visual Studio installer updates DLLs when installing an older version?

Tags: dll, windows-installer, vsinstaller

I recently noticed that my installer (VS 2008) does not remove the DLLs during uninstall.  This is not too much of a concern to me but the following is a concern:  when I install an *older* version of my software, it does not overwrite the DLLs -- it keeps the newer version.

When I am rolling back my system to an **older** version, I would like everything to roll back.  What is the best way to accomplish this?  Do I need to create a custom action to remove the DLLs at uninstall to be safe, or is there another way to remove them, or is there a setting to force the installer to always write the DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should ask yourself why didn't the installer remove the files, because it should and if it didn't then it's a BUG (or that the setup is waiting for a reboot to remove the files).
You can run you MSI with logging in order to discover what's going on there:
msiexec.exe /i  /l*v